# Meteor - data not available with Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to achieve something pretty simple: load a template and fill it with data. However, the template is rendered several times, and the first time with `null` data.

I found various posts about the issue stating that rendering occurs every time the subscription adds a record to the clients database, and tried applying proposed solutions, but I still have a first rendering without data. How can I fix that?

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});

Router.route('/team/:_id/cal', {

    name: 'calendar',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('userTeams',Meteor.user()._id),
            Meteor.subscribe('teamUsers', this.params._id)];
    },
    action : function () {
        console.log("action:"+this.ready());
        if (this.ready() && Template.currentData != null) {
            this.render();
        }
    },
    data: function(){
        var team = Teams.findOne({_id:this.params._id})
        console.log(JSON.stringify(team));
        return team;
    }
}
```

);

Console output

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/team/PAemezbavGEmWBNMy/plan
router.js:33 undefined
router.js:33 {"_id":"PAemezbavGEmWBNMy","name":"superteam","createdAt":"2015-10-22T11:51:10.994Z","members":["T6MpawQj75J2HgPi6","4T3StXAaR9iF4sK99","dDe2dJq3wjL2rFB43"]}
router.js:26 action:true
router.js:33 {"_id":"PAemezbavGEmWBNMy","name":"superteam","createdAt":"2015-10-22T11:51:10.994Z","members":["T6MpawQj75J2HgPi6","4T3StXAaR9iF4sK99","dDe2dJq3wjL2rFB43"]}
```